# Too many re-renders. React limits (Next JS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an error with the code below
( Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.)

The goal is to add a span on each item excepted the last one.

What is the best way to do that?

```
const Section = () => {

  const [lastItem, setlastItem] = React.useState(false);

  // rendu des Sections
  const sectionLentgh = Data.sections.length;
  const sectionList = Data.sections.map((item, i) => {
    
    // AJout du séparateur
    if (sectionLentgh === i + 1) {
      setlastItem(false);
    } else {
      setlastItem(true);
    }

    console.log(i);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <img src={`/images/${item.image}`}></img>
        <span style={{ backgroundImage:`url(/images/${item.image})` }}></span>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} />
        <span className={`${ lastItem ? styles.separator : '' }`}></span>
      </div>
    );
  })

  return (
    <>
    <div className={styles.sections}>
        {sectionList}
    </div>
    </>
  );

};

export default Section;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Section = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.sections}>
        {Data.sections.map((item, id) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <h2>{item.title}</h2>
            <img src={`/images/${item.image}`}></img>
            <span style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/images/${item.image})` }
            }></span>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} />
            <span className={`${id < (Data.sections.length - 1) ? styles.separator : ""}`}></span>
          </div>
        ))
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
};
```

or

```
const Section = () => {

  return (
    <>
      {Data.sections.map((item, id) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <div className={styles.sections} key={id}>
            <h2>{item.title}</h2>
            <img src={`/images/${item.image}`}></img>
            <span style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/images/${item.image})` }
            }></span>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} />

          </div>
          { id < (Data.sections.length - 1) &&
            <span className={styles.separator}></span>
          }
        </div>
      ))
      }
    </>
  );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the length of the array and compare it to the index of the iteration:

```
const Section = () => {
  const sectionLength = Data.sections.length;
  const sectionList = Data.sections.map((item, i) => {
    const lastItem = i === (sectionLength - 1);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <img src={`/images/${item.image}`}></img>
        <span style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/images/${item.image})` }}></span>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} />
        <span className={`${lastItem ? styles.separator : ""}`}></span>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.sections}>{sectionList}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Section;
```

Answer (score 0):

You enter an infinite loop because you call `setlastItem` in the map function, which in turn reruns on every render. Since setState triggers a new render, this causes the infinite loop.

What you want to is to put the generation of the sectionList in a useEffect, that reruns only every time the Data.sections changes.
Like this:

```
const Section = () => {
  const [sectionList, setSectionList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!Data.sections|| Data.sections.length < 2){
      setSectionList([]);
    } else {
     setSectionList(Data.sections.splice(-1, 1));
    }

  }, [Data.sections]);
    
  return (
      <div className={styles.sections}>
        {sectionList.map(item => (
           <div>
             <h2>{item.title}</h2>
             <img src={`/images/${item.image}`}></img>
             <span style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/images/${item.image})`}
               }></span>
             <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} />
             <span className={`${lastItem ? styles.separator : ""}`}></span>
           </div>
        )}
      </div>
  );
};
```

As you see, I separated the generation of the data from the jsx, which makes the code more easy to understand and rebuild, I find.